# How to create approval process in TFS process template?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, workflow

We have restrict control policy on our development cycle, and I am trying to see if I can create a approval workflow in TFS Process, which will formally approve work-items and schedule.

But it seems workflow in TFS is some-kind of simple ,compare to Windows Workflow.

Anyone would suggest a direction？

Comment: Do you mean you want to get approval before checking code? Do you use TFVC ot Git version control?

Comment: I am looking for approval process for work item state changing,scheduling.. etc.  For example, when a set of backlog created, it get a formal approval process,by sending an automatic email and approval, before put into backlog.

Answer (score 0):

Process templates define the objects and processes available to you when you create a team project. By customizing a process template, you customize one of more objects. Common types of customizations you can make include:

- Add a new field to an existing work item type (WIT)
- Modify the pick list of values for a field
- Change the workflow—States, Reasons, Transitions, Actions—of an
  existing WIT
- Edit the layout of a work item form
- Add or remove a work item type
- Change the process configuration or defaults associated with Agile
  tools

If you want to restrict who is allowed to make a transition from one state to another for a work item, you can use the `for` and `not` attributes of the **TRANSITION** element. As the following example shows, testers can reopen a bug but developers cannot.

```
<TRANSITION from="Closed" to="Active"  
   for="[Project]\Testers"  
   not="[Project]\Developers">  
   . . .  
</TRANSITION>
```

Useful links:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/reference/process-templates/customize-process?view=vsts
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/reference/change-workflow-wit?view=vsts

Comment: Is it possible to be dynamics for the "for" and "not" keyword? For example, if a variable "approved"="true", for="[Project]\ProjectManager" else for="[Project]\everyone"

Comment: No by default. You could only achieve updating a field during a workflow change.